# Is it possible to create a path to Excelfiles with VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I am building a report on Excel that has to be updated monthly. Therefore I get every month a new Excelfile with data that has to be summarized in the report.
The report consists of the calculations of the specific Excelfiles with the data for each month, for example the amount of male or female customers.

Is it possible to create a macro via VBA that creates a path to the new Excelfile so that I do not have to change the path to the file manually? In this case for example instead that I have to change the formula to `'...non_activated-2019-03'` by typing it in, Excel should do it automatically because there are over 60 of these calculations in which I would have to change the file.

```
=COUNTIFS('C:\Users\denni\Desktop\Reporting\Non Activated\[non_activated-2019-02.xlsx]non_activated-2019-02'!$M:$M;$B$9;'C:\Users\denni\Desktop\Reporting\Non Activated\[non_activated-2019-02.xlsx]non_activated-2019-02'!$B:$B;$C10)
```

Comment: There are a few ways of doing this, finding the latest file, or assuming something like "first Monday file comes in" etc.  Can you show what you've tried, and also how you want it.

Comment: So basically it is not even necessarily about finding the latest file or so(even though this would be nice as well) but more importantly about creating the path to another excel file.

`ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=COUNTIFS('non_activated-2019-01.xlsx'!C13,RC3)"
    Range("F6").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=COUNTIFS('non_activated-2019-01.xlsx'!C13,RC3)"
    Range("F7").Select` thats a fraction of  a macro that I recoreded and I was thinking about something like replacing `non-activated-2019-01` with a variable, which should be the path to the new file.

Comment: I wouldn't mind having to change each month manually the variable that would create a path to the newest folder. I thought about something looking like this:
`Sub MySub()
Dim file As String
file = "C:\Users\denni\Desktop\Reporting\Non Activated\non_activated-2019-03"
Range("F5").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=COUNTIFS(file!C13,RC3)"`

Comment: @Dirty Dan I've update my answer to include file opening and writing. With that functions, you can do almost everithing with your file. Check it out! :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible and I do it myself when I need to create reports and log files. Just add the following in your filename `String`:

```
filename = "...non_activated-" & Year(Date) & "-" & Month(Date)
```

---

#### Month Number with 0

If you want the month number to start with `0`, you can simply change the code like this:

```
Sub yourSub()
   '...
   filename = "...non_activated-" & Year(Date) & "-" & getMonthNumber(Date)
   '...
End Sub

Function getMonthNumber(data As Date) As String
    If Month(data) < 10 Then
        getMonthNumber = "0" & Month(data)
    Else
        getMonthNumber = Month(data)
    End If
End Function
```

---

#### Open your file

There're a lot of ways to open (and write on) your file. You can try this:

```
Open yourPath & yourFilename For Output As #1
Print #1, "Print somenthing on your file"
'Do your stuff
Close #1
```

Now you have your file saved on your path.

---

#### Notes

By using this method, every month it creates automatically a new file which you can easily find.

> Just remember to check if the **file exists**, otherwise it can launch
>   an exception.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the quick response, but when I am trying to run the macro, Excel asks me to which file that I want to create the path to and when I am selecting the file Excel shows in the cells the #Value error

Comment: @Dirty Dan I'm testing the code on my Excel and it's working. Try to check your references and try to launch Debug-> Compile and see if there're some errors.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a function like so in a cell, on a sheet, then reference the cell in formulas, then leave them alone.

For example `=GetLatestImportFile("C:\workspace\dummy data\")`

```
Function GetLatestImportFile(strPath As String, _
        Optional strLookFor As String = "non-activated")

Dim f As Scripting.FileSystemObject
Dim fld As Scripting.Folder
Dim fl As Scripting.File
Dim dt As Date

Set f = New Scripting.FileSystemObject
Set fld = f.GetFolder(strPath)

For Each fl In fld.Files

    If InStr(1, fl.Name, strLookFor) > 0 Then
        If fl.DateCreated > dt Then
            dt = fl.DateCreated
            GetLatestImportFile = fl.Name
        End If
    End If

Next fl

set f=nothing
set fld=nothing
set fl=nothing

End Function
```

Comment: I copied your code into the editor but it cannot execute the function in Excel.

Comment: Have you placed it in a module, and used `=GetLatestImportFile("C:\workspace\dummy data\")` with the correct folder?  You will also need to add the reference in VBA to "Scripting Runtime"

Comment: Yeah I've done all of them but it seems like Excel does not recognize  =GetImportFile() as a function

Comment: What is happening, put a breakpoint on the first line of the function and recalculate the sheet, see if the function is called.  I have tested in both VBA and with the excel function and it works.  Is the function in a module, not the sheet code.

Comment: Hmm, yeah the function is in a seperate module and not in the sheet code. I put the breakpooint but nothing happened

Comment: So you've not done something right.  Checklist from me is a) in a module b) Scripting.Runtime reference added c) formula entered correctly d) your path added e) your file search for `strLookFor`.   I cant see your maching, so I can not advise further.

Comment: Yeah actually seems like a problem with my Excel/VBA as I cannot execute any self created formula. I'm trying to figure out the problem. Anyways thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Macros in trust center?

Comment: Nope should all be enabled. My recorded macros are working but strangly the functions arent

Comment: Where are your macros though, personal workbook or the current workbook?

Comment: From the Personal Workbook

Comment: So my code is in a different workbook then.  Unfortunately I can not help you further on this, this is something you'll have to sort for your workbook.

Comment: Yes, in VBA does `debug.? GetLatestImportFile("C:\workspace\dummy data\")` return anything in the immediate window.  I'm sorry, but im going to have to leave this now, I cant see your machine, you'll have to sort this now.

Comment: Got the function working. But Excel has problems with the reference as it shows the #Value! error even though the references and the file should be correct. Even more strangely: for my first function everything works well and the correct value is calvulated but fo all other functions there is the #Value! error

Comment: Have you added the reference?

Comment: Yeah references and all were added but apparently they weren't recoginzed. Anyways, I found a different approach that works for the moment!

Answer (score 0):

So for now this code is doing quite well and replaces the old reference with the new one!

```
Sub MySub()
   Dim old as String
   Dim new as String
   Dim i as Integer

   old = "activated-2019-01"
   new = "activated-2019-02"
   For i=4 to 160
      Cells(i,"E").FormulaLocal = Replace(Cells(i,"F").FormulaLocal, old, new)
   Next i
End Sub
```